# Allocating A Large (5000+) Array

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I am working on an application were there are three possible sizes for the data entered:

- small: 1000 elements
- medium= 5000 elements
- large= 500,000 elements

The problem is that I can't allocate the large array. It seems that a size larger than 5000 is not accepted.

I get a run time error when I do the following:

```
long  size=1000;
char ch;
int arr[size];
ch=getch();

if(ch==..)
  size=...;
```

Sizes of 1000 and 5000 seem to work fine, but how can I make an array of size 500k in this way?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "cant allocate"? Are you getting an error? What is the message, and where do you get it? Note that 500000 elements is not 500K. It is probably 2Meg, as C `int`s are typically 4 bytes each.

Comment: i mean i get a run time error, by 500k i meant 500 thousand element not size

Comment: the runtime error is a stack overflow

Answer (score 10):

You can allocate such a big array on the heap:

```
int *arr;
arr = malloc (sizeof(int) * 500000);
```

Don't forget to check that allocation succeded (if not - malloc returns NULL).

And as pmg mentioned - since this array is not located in the stack, you have to `free` it once you finished working with it.

Comment: And remember to `free` the pointer once you're done working with it.

Answer (score 9):

Your stack can't hold that much data. You have to allocate big arrays on the heap as follows:

```
int *array = malloc (sizeof(int)*size);
```

As pmg pointed out remember to free your memory once your done.

```
free(array);
```

Comment: the language in the question is c

Comment: or, its C equivalent `int * array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size)`

Comment: please don't cast the value returned from malloc

Comment: don't cast the return value of `malloc`. It serves no useful purpose and may hide errors.

Comment: @David: does it make any difference?

Comment: @David I changed that but why is that not preferable ?

Comment: @pmg already explained. There are a gazillion posts on this site with more details.

Comment: @P.R.: you might want to [search for "cast malloc"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cast+malloc) and have all your questions answered -- even those questions you didn't know you have :)

Comment: @pmg Yeah I just did that. I actually have never casted malloc but for some reason decided to go all fancy and do it in this post. I guess I learned something too from this question :)

Comment: I like to use the object itself for the `sizeof` operator. If the type of data changes in future, only 1 piece of code needs to be changed: `int *array; array = malloc(nelems * sizeof *array);` ... `double *array; array = malloc(nelems * sizeof *array); /* same malloc as before */`

Answer (score 4):

It's too big for the stack. Instead you need to allocate it on the heap with malloc.