# Fortran: Array initialization exceeds maximum table size for the ``ir_list_tbl``

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran, lookup-tables

I'm trying to initialize a lookup table in Fortran using an include statement that declares the values of the LUT using a `DATA` statement. The LUT is declared like this:

```
REAL DIMENSION(400, 500, 15) :: my_array
INCLUDE '/path/to/my/file.incf'
```

And the include file looks like this:

```
...
DATA my_array (390:400, 499, 5) = / 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9 /
DATA my_array (1:10, 500, 5) = / 1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9 /
...
```

My real data isn't structured, so that the LUT structure really is necessary :) I want to compile it into the program so that I don't have to read it in at runtime.

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
ftn-237 crayftn: LIMIT SRC_RADIATION, File = /path/to/my/file.incf, Line = 127436 
  Maximum table size has been exceeded for the "ir_list_tbl".
```

As far as I understand it, `ir_list_tbl` is used for bookkeeping, but since I'm actually only saving the values positionally within a single variable, I don't understand the overhead here. We're talking about 3,000,000 values in a single array and not 3,000,000 top-level variables. What can I do better here?

Comment: You are trying to initialize a 3 million element array with DATA statements?  That is so unusual that it might be too much for the compiler.   I suggest reading the values from a file.

Comment: I agree that it would be the most natural thing to do, but this is being integrated into a weather model so one of the priorities is minimizing time spent on things like I/O. It seems like that'll be the way to go though.

Comment: If you make the file unformatted (sometimes called binary), the IO will be fast.  However, that will introduce some platform dependency.   You could provide native unformatted for common platform and text for everything else.  Or you could use HDF5 or FITS to provide platform independent "binary".

Comment: Even if you could embed the massive array, you have to do some sort of IO anyway - whether your OS is loading the executable prior to execution, or your executable is loading the input file at the start of execution. I expect the difference would be negligible if the input file is native unformatted.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your [stack size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746377/allocating-a-large-5000-array) has been exceeded if explicit-shape local array are created on the stack